# Get chapter length from id3 - tag

Tags: metadata, itunes, id3, podcast

I would like to get the Chapter length out of the id3 tags from a `.m4a` podcast file. I am using the PHP framework getID3() to analysis the file.
In the [data](http://pastebin.com/ZXibQtLS) I found an array with the amount of chapters and an attribute which calls "sample_duration" with an example value of around 50000. Now is my question how i can get the length in minutes, or do I get the length of chapters through offset attributes in the tags.
When I add all the sample_duration values i get 1988440, But in what unity is this measured? 
The length of the whole file is 55 minutes and 14 seconds.
To visualize the data you could use http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deeper analysis of the data, I found the "time_scale" attribute, with which I can calculate the chapter durations in seconds.